# What is the differences between File.GetCreationTime and fileInfo.CreationTime?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Currently i am using `File.GetCreationTime` in to get files that meet a certain criterion:

```
List<string> files =
     Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.doc", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
              .Where(x => x.Contains("SomeString"))
              .OrderByDescending(f => File.GetCreationTime(f))
              .Take(numberOfFiles)
              .ToList<string>();
```

And i want to add the option to get files that meet a certain criterion but only from the `last X days` so i need to change `File.GetCreationTime` into `fileInfo.CreationTime`

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: What do you need to know that's not already covered by the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx)?

Comment: Both return the same but the static `File.GetCreationTime` only needs to return that whereas a `FileInfo` object has many more informations whether you need them or not.

Comment: There is no difference, except one is static and the other is a property that can be called on an instance of a FileInfo.

Comment: If you need just creation time, then use static method of `File` class. Don't create instance of `FileInfo` - it makes sense only if you want to get several info about file to skip additional security checks

Comment: "so I need to change File.GetCreationTime into fileInfo.CreationTime". Why? Why do you want/need to do this? How will this help? How will it make a difference?

Comment: So how can i search for files only from the last X days ?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with query syntax, because its declarative and allows to introduce range variable for creation time of file:

```
var date = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-numberOfDays);
var searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly; // just to fit width of window

var files = from f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.doc", searchOption)
            let creationTime = File.GetCreationTime(f)
            where f.Contains("SomeString") && creationTime >= date
            orderby creationTime descending
            select f; // query will return IEnumerable<string>
```

If you want to use lambda syntax, then first option is projecting files into sequence of anonymous objects with file name and creation time:

```
 var files =
  Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.doc", searchOption)
           .Where(f => f.Contains("SomeString"))
           .Select(f => new { Name = f, CreationTime = File.GetCreationTime(f) })
           .Where(x => x.CreationTime >= date)              
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationTime)
           .Select(x => x.Name)
           .ToList();
```

Another option is usage of `FileInfo` - its much more readable than previous one, but has worse performance, because `FileInfo` instance should be created and initialized with information about file:

```
 var dir = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
 var files = 
       dir.EnumerateFiles("*.doc", searchOption)
          .Where(f => f.Name.Contains("SomeString") && f.CreationTime > date)
          .OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime)
          .Select(f => f.Name)
          .ToList();
```

NOTE: Thus you don't need all files from directory, then it's better to use [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead of getting array of all files.